# Reasons for fridge light to go out other than bulb

Tags: refrigerator

I have a GE fridge that looks 10-15 years old.  Recently, the light went out and I thought it was the bulb so I tried to replace it but it wasn't it.  The fridge works fine other than that.

What could be some other reasons the light stopped functioning?

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious thing here is that the switch has ceased to function ... the one which turns the light on and off. The switch is usually activated by use of the door.

Comment: Paulster, you're like a universal fix everything guru...  The truck been fixed, I think but I need to still change the rad cause the neck was bad and wasn't sealing the cap.

Comment: do you think that control unit inside the fridge (with the temp control, switch and light) can be replaced ?

Comment: Aren't the temp control and the switch separate? The switch should be replaceable ... Just depends on whether you can actually find a replacement for it. That really depends on the manufacturer to me, though.

Answer (score 1):

Do a total cost of ownership calculation. A fridge is one of the more expensive appliances you can own. If you have an old, inefficient one, the cost of energy burned may easily be  more than the cost of purchasing and operating a new energy-efficient one. If you start repairing old appliances, you could be throwing good money after bad.

In the seventies I worked for the USAF in Germany. There was a big realignment of units and a call went out for units to send us any spare appliance inventory. Some small Army unit in the middle of nowhere sent us a new unit, still in the carton. We unpacked, tested and issued the 1950s era fridge to some unsuspecting family. It was beautiful.